# Have I succesfully removed the pointer from the heap?

Tags: c++, file

The following code shows me getting the filesize of a certain file to then later on make a large enough buffer to ensure I can store all the files content in this buffer. So what I did was allocating it on the heap, because I couldn't know if the file is huge or not etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

size_t filesize(FILE* f) {
    size_t size;
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    return size;
}

char* read_file(std::string name) {
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, name.c_str(), "rb");
    size_t size = filesize(f);
    char* buffer = new char[size+1];

    memset(buffer, 0, size+1);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size+1, f);
    fclose(f);

    return buffer; //this is the buffer with the content to send
}

int main() {
    char* buffer = read_file("main.cpp");

    printf("%s", buffer);

    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = nullptr;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**My question is, have I successfully deleted**

```
char* buffer = new char[size+1];
```

**from the heap by doing this:**

```
char* buffer = read_file("main.cpp");
delete[] buffer;
buffer = nullptr;
```

**Or does it still remain somewhere?
And if it does, how would I pin-point it and delete it?**

Any other tips on how to handle raw pointers are appreciated as well.

Comment: Tip #1:  don't use a raw pointer.  Use an suitable container, such as a `std::vector<char>` instead, which handles the gory details of the memory management for you.  Harder to make that kind of mistake.  Let's you concentrate on making more interesting mistakes.

Comment: The array does not exist but its remains may still be lying around where the array used to be. Just like poor uncle Edward after that unfortunate mushroom incident last October.

Comment: "getting the filesize of a certain file to then later on make a large enough buffer" sounds like a potential [TOCTTOU](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) bug waiting to happen. The file might grow between your check/allocation an the time when you actually read the file.

Comment: Just use and return a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your code is correctly deleting the buffer.

C++ has various ways to handle this for you though so you don't need to worry about it and will be less likely to make mistakes and forget to free the buffer in some or all code paths, e.g. its easy to make mistakes like this:

```
int main()
{
  char* buffer = read_file("main.cpp");
  if ( buffer[0] != 'A' )
  {
     std::cout << "data is invalid\n";
     return 1; // oops forgot to free buffer
  }
  delete[] buffer;
  // data is valid
  return 0;
}
```

One option is to use `std::unique_ptr` which will free the buffer for you when it goes out of scope:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<char[]> read_file(std::string name) {
    ....
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[size+1]);
    ....
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = read_file("main.cpp");
  if ( buffer[0] != 'A' )
  {
     std::cout << "data is invalid\n";
     return 1; // buffer is freed automatically
  }
  buffer.reset(); // can manually free if we are finished with buffer before it goes out of scope
  // data is valid
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return a `std::string`?

Comment: @Galik depends what is in the data, yes if its textual data and is going to be manipulated as such then a `std::string` is probably best, for binary data `std::string` makes less sense. `std::string` may also allocate more memory than is required to fit the data. `std::string` is also easy to accidentally copy whereas `std::unique_ptr` wont let you copy it.